# How to call a Rootviewcontroller on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iOS application launch im checking wether user is registered user or new user(like facebook & skype),
than if user is not register i'm navigating app to register screen with my App delegate:

```
    if (user != register){

        RegisterViewController *registerViewController = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
                RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:registerViewController];

        self.viewController = revealController;

        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

        self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }else {

FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
            RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

RevealController *revealController = [[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:navigationController rearViewController:rearViewController];

self.viewController = revealController;

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

This way if user is not registereds I now have register screen as a main window,

My problem is : after user finish registration im im getting two Navigation controller on top of my screen

im using:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:revealController animated:YES];
```

to navigate application to my main viewController since user is now registered,

how to fix this and is there any other way to fix register user issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you need another root view controller, why not to set it instead of pushing to another navController stack:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = revealController;
```